# Google Drive Share with my Apps workgroup without having to add them manually

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I thought the video about sharing with my workgroup mean that I didn't have to add my teammates as editors if I allowed my company to see and edit a doc:

[image]

So far I had to add them to the list to get them to see the document on the Shared With Me list. Is there a way to share a document company-wide without having to manually select which members are allowed?

Comment: I have a feeling its a known bug (choosing 'people at organisation can find' not actually working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you share with people individually, it will appear on their "Shared with me" list. If you share via a domain/find (or group) it will not appear there (but will appear in search).

One effective approach to make team collaboration work smoothly is to create a folder (for your team/project/org), share the folder with domain/find and then tell people to search for that folder and drag it to their "My Drive". Any docs put into that folder will inherit the security of the folder and be visible to people who have the folder it in My Drive.

Comment: Good idea on the folder fix - this is one of the worst implementations of group sharing I can think of. Note: as of 3/11/2013 - this fix does not work however though perhaps a temporary glitch on the Google side.

Comment: Searching for folder name does not yield any results here.

Answer (score 1):

Peter Herrmann’s method does not work for me. I have created both a document and a folder shared via the "People at acomwholesale can find and edit". When instructed to search from the drive search field, it returns no results.

For a work around, I have shared the folder with my company via the enter email address, but that should not be the solution. I'm luckily I only have a few employees, someone that has 100's of employees would be having to enter each email—unless of course you have a "***ALL***@domain.com" email address.

Comment: Please note that "above" has no context in relation to answers, since answers can be sorted in different ways.